# Initialize unordered_map in the initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14, unordered-map

I'm trying to find a solution to what may be a very trivial problem. I would like to initialize my `const unordered_map` in the class initializer list. However I'm yet to find the syntax that the compiler (GCC 6.2.0) will accept. A code link is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33c059ae615b6019).

```
#include <unordered_map>

class test {
 public:
    test()
      : map_({23, 1345}, {43, -8745}) {}

 private:
   const std::unordered_map<long, long> map_;
 };
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In constructor 'test::test()':
main.cpp:6:36: error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_map<long int, long int>::unordered_map(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
  : map_({23, 1345}, {43, -8745}) {}
                                ^
```

Are the complex constants not allowed to be initialized in the initializer list? Or the syntax has to be different?

Comment: Use braces instead of the parentheses.

Comment: To add to Vlad, the error is raised because you are passing 2 arguments (2 array literals) instead of 1 nested array, so adding an extra pair of {} makes your argument `{{23, 1345}, {43, -8745}}` which may be what you want.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow good catch, thank you. I've missed it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use braces instead of the parentheses

```
class test {
 public:
    test()
      : map_{{23, 1345}, {43, -8745}} {}

 private:
   const std::unordered_map<long, long> map_;
 };
```

Comment: Why the braces instead of parenthesis?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Because there is no such a constructor in the class std::unordered_map. On the other hand you could write map_({{23, 1345}, {43, -8745}})

Answer (score 3):

Use curly braces instead of the parentheses because if you use parentheses it's calling the constructor that best matches your arguments instead of the overloaded constructor with a parameter of type initializer_list.

Using parentheses and curly braces have the same effect until there's an overloaded constructor taking initializer_list type as a parameter. Then when you use curly braces, the compiler is going to bend over backwards to try to call that overloaded constructor.

for example:

```
Foo( 3 ) is calling Foo( int x ) constructor;
Foo{ 3 } is calling Foo( initializer_list<int> x ) constructor;

but if there's no Foo( initializer_list<int> x ) constructor

then Foo( 3 ) and Foo{ 3 } are both calling Foo( int x ) constructor.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates multiple overloaded constructors?